# Adding a New Item has been loaded, Indicator Image to an Item after its been Loaded to a webpage from a Folder in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I added a feature to my script that adds files from a folder in a SharePoint library onto a webpage, to include an indicator showing this is a new item.   I accomplished this using the provide script example.  But what I’m having trouble figuring out is how to extend the time pass the upload date and current date condition/connection.

In my script I added a conditional statement stating if the file upload date equals the current date then show the new indicator image, if not then do not show then new indicator image.  Once the upload passes the current date the image indication is removed.

Any ideas on how I can extend the new indicator 5 days past the upload/current date statement.  I hope this is not too confusing to grasp.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
getFilesFromFolder("/sites/dcsa/ep/New%20Pages/resources").done(function(data){
    $.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){

    if (item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0] == curday('-')) {

    $("#column1").append('<li class="linkData" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a href="' + 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov' +     item.ServerRelativeUrl + '" target="_blank"><img class="newArrow" style="width: 60px; position: relative; right: 5px; top: 0px;"src="../SiteAssets/SitePages/Test Page/icons/arrow-with_new2.gif" alt="logo">' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "") + " - "   + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0]  + '</a></li>');

        } else {

    $("#column1").append('<li class="linkData" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"><a href="' + 'https://intelshare.intelink.gov' + item.ServerRelativeUrl + '" target="_blank">' + item.Name.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")  + " - "   + item.TimeCreated.split('T')[0]  + '</a></li>');
}

   });
});

var curday = function(sp){
today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //As January is 0.
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) dd='0'+dd;
if(mm<10) mm='0'+mm;
return (yyyy+sp+mm+sp+dd);
};

function getFilesFromFolder(serverRelativeUrlToFolder){
  return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api  web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"+serverRelativeUrlToFolder+"')/files", method: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
       });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try comparing Date objects instead of strings:

```
var spDate = new Date(item.TimeCreated) //example: '2015-10-30T05:00:00Z'
var newTillDate = new Date();
newTillDate.setDate(newTillDate.getDate() + 5);
if(spDate <= newTillDate)
    //Show your new badge
else
    //Don't show your new badge
```

This should allow you to get rid of your curday function as well. You may need to play around with it though to handle timezones properly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply back.  I tried the above method but I get this error:  Object doesn't support property or method 'addDays'.  Any ideas or am I missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: Ah right. Try newTillDate.setDate(newTillDate.getDate() + 5); Edited answer above.

Comment: The update resolved the error but the method adds 5 days to the current date; making the current date Jan 8, 20.  Now that the Logical  Operators are set to <= the new badge shows on everything lower then Jan 8, 20 (I have items loaded many days before the current day, so the new badge shouldn't display) and not just on the newly added item.  I'm trying to have the items show the badge for 5 days then go away after the 5 days end (this is 5 day after a person revisit the sharepoint page).  I hope this make sense.

Comment: I believe I got it working with a slight modification of the script you provided.  I modified your script, newTillDate.setDate(newTillDate.getDate() + 5) to spDate.setDate(newTillDate.getDate() + 5).  And I reverse the "Show your Badge" and "Don't show your badge" function, and that did the trick.  Thank you for the assist and getting me on the correct track.